# Joomla component .inc file

Tags: joomla

I'm building a component that sends email messages in certain situations.  I would rather not have the email HTML directly within my php code, therefore I would like to put the html into a .inc file.  I'm not sure if best practices dictate where such files should be placed...the media folder perhaps?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent for [the `/media/` directory](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Media_files) is that it contains all the assets you need to be "web visible" for your component. So if your component displays images, uses custom CSS, JS file etc that's where they would go.

The point of the media directory is so that in future updates to Joomla! the core code files can be moved to a non-web visible location to improve overall security.

Having said that if you will have executable or sensitive content in your `.inc` files then I would create a `asset` directory within the `/administrator/components/com_yourcomponenet/`.